# PostgreSQL ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE by giving a ROW type variable instead of spelling out all columns?

Tags: postgresql-14

PostgreSQL 14: This works splendedly:

```
DECLARE 
  _context audit.etl_failed_execution_contexts;
BEGIN
snip...
INSERT INTO audit.etl_failed_execution_contexts VALUES (_context.*);
```

But there is a unique constraint, so I want something like:

```
INSERT INTO audit.etl_failed_execution_contexts
VALUES (_context.*)
ON CONFLICT (correlation_id) DO UPDATE SET (*) = ROW(_context.*);
```

Instead of:

```
INSERT INTO audit.etl_failed_execution_contexts
VALUES (_context.*)
ON CONFLICT (correlation_id) DO UPDATE SET 
  col1 = excluded.col1, 
  col2 = excluded.col2, 
  snip...;
```

Doesn't seem possible from docs, other questions on the web, but hoping anyway. Thanks.

Comment: No, not possible. You will have to list each column explicitly